# Difference between ObjLoader and ObjLoader2 in Three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, .obj

What's the main difference between this two classes, [ObjLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader) and [ObjLoader2](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader2)?

In which case we should use one or another?

Why there are two classes? Is one more stable or efficient than the other?

It's not very clear for me when I read the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

I have sometimes wondered this too..
So I decided this time to jump down the rabbit hole (writing this post as I go down the hole).

This is what I have found.

- The first commit of OBJLoader2 had the comment "Added Geometry2 based OBJLoader." by mrdoob as seen [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commits/master/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader2.js).
- Geometry2 seems to have been part of some experiments to combine the ease of use of Geometry with the performance of BufferGeometry. An issue mentioning Geometry2 can be [viewed here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4386).
- There are recent commits for both [OBJLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commits/master/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js) and [OBJLoader2](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commits/master/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader2.js).
- All the recent commits seem to be from a single person (kaisalmen)

So, It seems to me that OBJLoader2 is meant to be a more performant loader for OBJ files. Having a look at The main commiter's github page reveals a repository specifically for the OBJLoader2 class.
**There is documentation on the OBJLoader2 class in the authors [github repository here](https://github.com/kaisalmen/WWOBJLoader)**

Comment: I'm still wondering in which case we should use one or another. Is OBJLoader2 experimental and we should use the original if we want a stable version? For example, and I'm just guessing, OBJLoader2 could be faster but OBJLoader could be able to load more models and in that case, I would use one or another depending on what I want to achieve in my website.

Answer (score 9):

Found some [interesting comparisons by the creator here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/13663):

```
╔════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ Feature                            ║ OBJLoader ║ OBJLoader2 ║
╠════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║Handle all face types               ║     x     ║     x      ║
║Support for points and lines        ║     x     ║     x      ║
║Negative face indices               ║     x     ║     x      ║
║Support Ngons                       ║     x     ║     x      ║
║Flat/Smooth Multi-Materials         ║           ║     x      ║
║Indexed Rendering                   ║           ║     x      ║
║Handle Face-Type change inside group║           ║     x      ║
║Deactivate console logging          ║           ║     x      ║
║Load MTLs via MTLLoader if desired  ║           ║     x      ║
╚════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 5):

For now, The main difference is that the OBJLoader2 supports web worker for asynchronous loading. And it offer a choice for user between syn and asyn.